# Unable to get Keycloak client initiated client account linking to work

Tags: laravel, keycloak

The request to start the client iniated account linking fails.

The console is showing a WARN of type: CLIENT_INITIATED_ACCOUNT_LINKING_ERROR with error: invalid_token.

The url was generated as described here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#client-initiated-account-linking, by php backend system.

Also making sure to use UTF8 encoding when generating the hash

All prerequisites as describe it the section have been fulfilled.

Im' using Keycloak 15.0.2 and Laravel with Socialite to authenticate users.

This is how the hash is generated.

```
$keycloack_user = Socialite::driver('keycloak')->user();
$bearerToken = $keycloack_user->token;
$tokenParts = explode(".", $bearerToken);
$tokenHeader = base64_decode($tokenParts[0]);
$tokenPayload = base64_decode($tokenParts[1]);
$jwtHeader = json_decode($tokenHeader);
$jwtPayload = json_decode($tokenPayload);

$client_id = $jwtPayload->azp;
$host = $jwtPayload->iss;

$session_state = $jwtPayload->session_state;

$nonce = Str::random(20);
$provider = "google";

$input = $nonce . $session_state . $client_id . $provider;
$utf8encoded = utf8_encode($input);
$hashed = hash('sha256', $utf8encoded);
$encoded = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($hashed), '+/', '-_'), '=');
```

Then the linking url is constructed as shown below:

```
$redirect_uri = urlencode(...);
$full_url = $host . "/broker/". $provider ."/link?client_id=". $client_id ."&redirect_uri=". $redirect_uri ."&nonce=". $nonce ."&hash=" . $encoded;
```

I'm currently testing a my local machine, without using https for any of the applications. Loging in works fine and when inspecting the JWT token, the needed role mappings are present:

```
"account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
```

But when accessing the url it says "Invalid request" and the Keycloak console indicates the token is invalid.

Update: Solution was to return the result of the hash method as raw binary data

```
$hashed = hash('sha256', $utf8encoded, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to work on the same task lately but with the client implemented in JavaScript. I was also stuck for quite a while till I realized how uncommonly keycloak is expecting the encoded hash value. You need to consider following two points:

- Encode the hash string into hexadecimal before base64 conversion
- Replace `+` by `-` and `/` by `_`. Besides that remove trailing `=` symbols

Below you find a working snippet written in JS:

```
import sjcl from "sjcl";

hexToBase64(hexstring) {
        return btoa(hexstring.match(/\w{2}/g).map(function(a) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));
        }).join(""));
    },

// Assume nonce, session_state, clientId, provider to be given
var data = nonce + session_state + clientId + provider;
var myBitArray = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(data)
var hashedData = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(myBitArray)
var base64HashedData = this.hexToBase64(HashedData)
base64HashedData = base64HashedData.replaceAll('+','-').replaceAll('/','_').replaceAll('=','')
```

`base64HashedData` is then what you need to pass as hash query parameter to the `link` endpoint of keycloak.

Comment: This solved the issue I was facing. It was unclear from the documentation that the sh256 hash was expected as hex. Thanks to your remark the fix to my example was quit simple, the php hash method accepts an optional third parameter "binary" which will output raw binary data. Setting that to true was to only change required